# shortcode conflict with facebook.php

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

I am using Wordpress to build a facebook application. The application uses a plugin for hosting a small quiz, and I used a wordpress plugin for the quiz.

However, after this I had to include a like gate for the application page, so I included facebook.php in the index page. Now the quiz plugin is no longer working.

Can anybody let me know if the facebook.php can cause conflicts with the Wordpress plugins and  if yes, how can it be circumvented?

Comment: This should be asked on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't conflict because the Facebook PHP isn't Wordpress specific and is a self contained class, so there's unlikely to be any function naming issues etc, unless you are using a plugin to load the Facebook API? Have a look at your error logs in the site route and plugin folders.